# Error with firebase Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

can anyone help me fix this error, I'm just starting with firebase and having a lot of trouble.
I don't see what I'm doing wrong and could not find any help in similar topics. Maybe I did something wrong when settings up firestore. Any help will be welcome.
I have attached a picture of my console and also my firebase component and users component [![

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import fire from './fire';

export default class Users extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
         email: "",
         fullName: "",
         score: 0,
    
        };
    }

    updateInput = e => {
        this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
      }

      addUser = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    const db = fire.firestore();
    db.settings({
      timestampsInSnapshots: true
    });
    db.collection('users').add({
      name: this.state.fullName,
      age: this.state.email
    });
    this.setState({
      fullName: '',
      email: ''
    });
  };

    
  
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <form onSubmit={this.addUser}>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="fullname"
            placeholder="Full name"
            onChange={this.updateInput}
          />
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            onChange={this.updateInput}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'


var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDQYq4eLROxHG0rIZ8rggZ31_lKebWeptw",
    authDomain: "projectever-ea1f7.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "projectever-ea1f7",
    storageBucket: "projectever-ea1f7.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "465265606000",
    appId: "1:465265606000:web:959b53535db63632ba63b5"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
 const fire =  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

 export default fire;
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL4nb.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL4nb.png)

Comment: It appears that you have posted sensitive/private information. If that's the case, please reset your passwords and/or revoke API keys and tokens, as they are considered compromised when posted on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Try implementing these firestore security rules in your project and publish them.

Comment: I changed the firestore security rules but when I try to publish them, I have an error saying : Error saving rules - An unknown error occurred